# Multiple images placed in 1 larger image with scaling applied

Tags: java, image, algorithm

I'm struggling to get all images into a larger image; scaling is applied outside (can be one of multiple things, not relayed to the image). These are the steps I'm taking at the moment:

1. calculate the size of the large image (say 1000x1000)
2. For each image in the array calculate the aspect ratio. (they are all different)
3. find what % scale it needs (say 6% of total image)
4. take the square root of the total image size / aspect ratio to find one dimension
5. Multiply the side we know by the aspect ratio to get the other dimension.
6. Scale the image down to the new calculated value
7. (**Now heres where im having trouble**) Find a space on the larger image which will fit the scaled image in. If there are multiple choose one at random.
8. Repeat until image is filled. There are around 4000 images which need to fit in.

There are quite a lot of really small images (1x1, 2x1 2x2 etc) which are useful for filling. The problem is the random method and the first space method are not great and usually end up with some images that wont fit on.

Is there an algorithm which can choose the best place to put the image knowing all of the dimensions involved? Rotation is fine (so a 100x50 can be treated as a 50X100)

I'm using Java currently but the problem would apply to any language.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithms you're looking at fall under a field called integer programming. This is a class of solutions to optimization problems where all the inputs are integers (rather than real numbers). The specific problem you're asking about goes by the name [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). There's example code on this problem on [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu).

Comment: Ill look in to that, That solution doesnt seem to allow rotation but being an NP hard problem it may be very difficult to allow rotation

Comment: @user1281385 It's important to have proper respect for these kinds of problems. It's thinking that they are easier than they actually are that's the biggest hazard. You seem to have developed that appreciation for this one, though.